# Endomorphism which maps orthogonal vectors into orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

Let $T:\mathbb{R^4} \to \mathbb{R^4}$ which maps orthogonal vectors into orthogonal vectors. Is true or false that:
a) $T$ is an isomorphism?
b) $\langle u,v\rangle=\langle T(u),T(v)\rangle$ $\forall\ u,v \in \mathbb{R^4} $?

For the point a. I don't know what to do or to find a counterexample; for the second one I could find a counterexample in the case $u=v$?

Comment: What if $T$ mapped everything to $0$? Wouldn't $T$ map orthogonal vectors into orthogonal vectors?

Comment: Please note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, [as is explained here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could answer any of the following. Where did you come across this question? What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Ok, but if $T$ is not a null map? Since we are in finite dimension $T$ is an isomorphism iff T is injective. So, let $v \in Ker(T)$, i.e. $T(v)=0$, and now i want to prove that $v=0$.